# Looking for low-maintenance URLs to load jQuery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working with some legacy code that uses the following two lines in many places:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The first of these two lines seems to me to be always up-to-date (or at least, it does not become dated as new versions of jQuery get released).  Hence, I consider this a relatively "low-maintenance" URL.

In contrast, the second line is clearly liable to becoming obsolete as new versions of jQuery UI are released.

What's the jQuery UI-equivalent of the first line?

Comment: why don't you download them and host them locally?

Comment: there is a risk of breaking changes from new versions if yo use the latest file always

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js I think it is. Not sure though. The version in that link is 1.10.2, even though the latest is 1.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, there doesn't seem to be a link quite as low-maintenance as the jQuery one in your question. However, there is one that is *almost* as nice:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js

or "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js" in code to be http/https-agnostic.

This will give you the latest 1.x version. When version 2 is release, I assume you could simply update the link to use "2" instead of "1" and be good for a good while longer.